Intel IGCL API. cltinit always returns CTL_RESULT_ERROR_INVALID_NULL_HANDLE
I just started with this API and try to run examples.
Unfortunately ctlinit always fails with  CTL_RESULT_ERROR_INVALID_NULL_HANDLE
    ctl_init_args_t CtlInitArgs;
    ctl_api_handle_t hAPIHandle;
    CtlInitArgs.AppVersion = CTL_MAKE_VERSION(CTL_IMPL_MAJOR_VERSION, CTL_IMPL_MINOR_VERSION);
    CtlInitArgs.flags = 0;
    CtlInitArgs.Size = sizeof(CtlInitArgs);
    CtlInitArgs.Version = 0;
    ZeroMemory(&CtlInitArgs.ApplicationUID, sizeof(ctl_application_id_t));

    try
    {
        Result = ctlInit(&CtlInitArgs, &hAPIHandle);

From the documentation:
CTL_APIEXPORT ctl_result_t CTL_APICALL ctlInit(ctl_init_args_t
*pInitDesc, ctl_api_handle_t *phAPIHandle)

    Control Api Init.

        Control Api Init

    Parameters:

            pInitDesc – [in][out] App’s control API version

            phAPIHandle – [in][out][release] Control API handle

    Returns:

            CTL_RESULT_SUCCESS

            CTL_RESULT_ERROR_UNINITIALIZED

            CTL_RESULT_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST

            CTL_RESULT_ERROR_INVALID_NULL_POINTER

                nullptr == pInitDesc

                nullptr == phAPIHandle

            CTL_RESULT_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_VERSION - “Unsupported version”

None of the parameters are nullptr
It fails when calling  result = pfnInit(pInitDesc, phAPIHandle);
Maybe someone knows how to override this problem.
Both C++ & C tags used as it is API for both languages. The example code is in C++

The only other result for that code is an issue that was closed due to unsupported hardware. Not something StackOverflow can help you with.

@Botje indeed. You are right. Did not expect it :( Thank you
